# glCheckFramebufferStatus / GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNDEFINED

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opengl-es, yocto

I try to port an GLES 3.1 application from a host Linux/Ubuntu to an arm Linux/Yocto. Suddenly the function glCheckFramebufferStatus fails with error code GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNDEFINED as well as glClear and glDrawArrays.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xhtml

The API says that this happens "if target is the default framebuffer, but the default framebuffer does not exist. "

There apparently is no problem with FBOs index >= 1. I configure the attachments for these explicitly with glRenderbufferFramebuffer.

The problem only arises on the Yocto board, not on the Ubuntu desktop.

What can cause a default frame buffer to disappear or not getting created, but its FBOs are still intact?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that a PBuffer surface was created with dimensions (0,0). Seemingly some implementations see this as an opportunity to get rid of the default framebuffer altogether.